# Field not lining up in Bootstrap Horizontal Form

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a horizontal form in Angular using Bootstrap. I have one date field that is just slightly misaligned. The input field of the IsMessedUp datepicker is aligned to the left compared to the input fields above it. I'd also ideally like it to be the same width of the "Sixth Thing" Calendar element.

[image]

The calendar element code is here:

```
 <div class="form-group row">

                    <label class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-7 control-label">IsMessedUp Date: </label>

                        <p class="input-group col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                                   ng-model="ismessedupdt"
                                   is-open="ismessedupdt.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"
                                   datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                                   ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default input-sm" ng-click="open3()"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
                        </p>

                </div>
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k0c0e68n/

Answer (score 0):

You should be removing the padding-left and padding-right for input-group [class*="col-"] for the p tag which is adding the extra space to the mentioned input element(isMessedUpDate)

Workaround: Remove the input-group class with custom class inputGroup or something and specify the class something like this:

```
.inputGroup {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Raghu9972/k0c0e68n/1/

This may not be a right approach, change it accordingly :)